# When to .removeObserver ?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, geofire

The app should load only locally made posts. 
Using GeoFire a have a branch "`posts_location`" in FB. 
I want to populate '`nearbyPostsKeys`' array first, then load those specific posts from FB's branch posts that has reference `REF_POSTS.`

In `viewDidLoad`, I call for a func that has a completion handler(data from FB).

Here is func declaration that takes the completion handler:

```
func populateNearbyAndPassIt(completion:@escaping ([String])->()) {

    let theGeoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: DB_BASE.child("posts_location"))
    let location = CLLocation(latitude: Location.sharedInstance.currentLatitude, longitude: Location.sharedInstance.currentLongitude)
    let circleQuery = theGeoFire!.query(at: location, withRadius: 6.0)

     let newRefHandle: FIRDatabaseHandle = circleQuery!.observe(.keyEntered, with: { (key, location) in

        self.nearbyPostsKeys.append(key!)
        completion(self.nearbyPostsKeys)
    })
}
```

And here's how I call for that func in 'viewDidLoad':

```
 populateNearbyAndPassIt{(nearbyPostsKeys) in

        //populate 'posts' based on 'nearby..'

        for key in nearbyPostsKeys {
            let postRef = DataService.ds.REF_POSTS.queryOrdered(byChild: key)
            postRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                self.posts = []
                if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                    for snap in snapshot {
                        if let postDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                            let key = snap.key
                            let post = Post(postKey: key, postData: postDict)
                            self.posts.append(post)
                        }
                    }
                }
                self.posts.reverse()

                print("Zhenya: here are all local posts data: \(self.posts)")
            })
        }
    }
```

While having 3 posts on specified location here is what happened:

The .observe is called. 1 posts being retrieved and appends to nearbyPostsKeys -> the completion handler is called. and array with 1 element is passed... and the loop continues.

I wish i could wait until 'nearbyPostsKeys' array is populated and only then pass it as completion handler.

I also learned about `.removeObserver` func that can stop `.observe` func but wherever i put it like this:

```
    let newRefHandle: FIRDatabaseHandle = circleQuery!.observe(.keyEntered, with: { (key, location) in

        self.nearbyPostsKeys.append(key!)
        completion(self.nearbyPostsKeys)
    })
    circleQuery!.removeObserver(withFirebaseHandle: newRefHandle)
```

it looks as nearbyPostsKeys aren't passed at all.

Please advice on either better logic or on how to use `.removeObserver`.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove observers when your view controller deinitializes:

```
deinit {
    circleQuery!.removeObserver(withFirebaseHandle: newRefHandle)
}
```

Just make `circleQuery` a property of your viewcontroller.

Comment: if you do this in deinit, you have to make sure that you make the observer weak: with: {[weak self] (key, location) in , otherwise the observer stays in memory, and also check: if newRefHandle != nil { circleQuery!.removeObserver(withFirebaseHandle: newRefHandle)}